# Printing images in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I am trying to `print` images in the `html` page. say some 100 images, one in each page.
I added the image in the html content and added it in the `iframe` tag and tried printing. the images are cuttoff at the bottom and the rest of the part moves to the next page. How do I overcome this?

I have attached a simple code snippet to print a simple image. Please, try running the code snippet and suggest me a solution to print the image in a single page in all browsers(ie,ff and chrome)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint>

<head>
 
</head>

<body>

  <button id="btn1" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Print</button>
  <br/>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFvfE.jpg" style="border:1px solid" />

</body>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    //window.print();
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.name = "printFrame";
    iframe.style.position = "absolute";
    iframe.style.top = "-100000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var frameDoc = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.document ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint><head><style>@media print {div { page-break-inside: avoid;} @page{margin:0;} body{margin:0;}}</style></head><body><center>');
    frameDoc.document.write('<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFvfE.jpg" style="border:1px solid;margin:0px;display:block"/></div><br/>');
    frameDoc.document.write('</center></body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.frames["printFrame"].focus();
      window.frames["printFrame"].print();
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    }, 500);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your document a height, then set the images to fill up as much space as the parent element (html,body) allows:

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
img { height: 100%; width: auto; }
```

This seems to fix everything:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
img { height: 100%; width: auto; display: block; }
@media print { 
    body { margin: 0; }
    img { box-sizing: border-box; }
    br, button { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must need to write @media query for print your html or web page. I am using @media query for print web page. See below link.

http://www.richmondau.com/

You got the solution.